# Is there any software like 'Network Magic' for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, network

I really like Cisco's 'Network Magic' software; but the site says they no longer support Mac.. Does anyone know of any software like it, that is supported on Mac?

Comment: From looking at what Cisco's "Network Magic" actually does, it's no wonder Cisco discontinued the Mac version, all the features are already built in to Mac OSX.  What feature of "Network Magic" were you using that isn't available on OSX ?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to do all the repairs and such. And how to see people who are on your network, ect.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "do all the repairs", but to check out who is on your network is as easy as opening up a finder window and clicking on the "SHARED" arrow (which should be just below your "DEVICES" on the left hand side of your finder window.

Comment: did you ever find a answer to this question? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: Maybe you guys looking for an answer to this question could list some specific Network Magic features that you're looking to replace. It was a feature-rich program for sure and it's unlikely there's one single program for OS X that covers what Network Magic did. But specific features could have specific answers.

Comment: @john - You might as well ask a new version of this question but add some detail what specifically you want the app to do for you on OSX. It's looking like no-one here can guess what functions of the app need to run on OS X and make an answer. Or you could check on SuperUser where more people might be familiar with what the windows version of the software does.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some network monitoring & management tools for Mac OS X you may want to have a look at (although I haven't found a direct hit I guess). For example, 
`Casper Suite`, `InterMapper`, `IPNetMonitorX`, `Lithium 5.0`, `AutoScan-Network`, 
`DeployStudio`, ...

To see who is on your network you may use [Ntop](http://homepage.mac.com/duling/halfdozen/).

Since Mac OS X is a Unix-based operating system, there are also command line tools that allow you to manage other Macs remotely via SSH. For example, `systemsetup`, `networksetup` and `screencapture`.

And, last but not least (as already pointed out by mrbitch), there is quite some 'Network Magic' functionality that ships with Mac OS X by default (see, for example, the 'Sharing' system preference pane).